# Org mode spreadsheet programmatic remote references

Tags: emacs, spreadsheet, org-mode, remoteobject

I keep my budget in org-mode and have been pleased with how simple it is. The simplicity fails, however, as I am performing formulas on many cells; for instance, my year summary table that performs the same grab-and-calculate formulas for each  month. I end up with a massive line in my +TBLFM. This would be dramatically shorter if I could programmatically pass arguments to the formula. I'm looking for something like this, but working:

```
| SEPT   |
| #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: @2$1=remote(@1,$tf)
```

Elsewhere I have a table named SEPT and it has field named "tf". This function works if I replace "@1" with "SEPT" but this would cause me to need a new entry in the formula for every column.

Is there a way to  get this working, where the table itself can specify what remote table to call (such as the SEPT in my example)?

Comment: Just on the top of my head, you can pass variables from tables to org-babel code blocks, and you may be able to put some elisp in the TBLFM. Combining these may achieve something (I don't know if you can inline org-babel in TBLFM, sounds like a bit of a stretch…), but I don't know of the `remote` function you call for being built-in. I'd love to know the answer though, if you find more about it, please tell us. Maybe I'll gave it a try someday.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can't do this with built-in `remote` and you need to use `org-table-get-remote-range`. Hopefully this better suits your needs than the answer given by artscan (I used his/her example):

```
| testname1 | testname2 |
|-----------+-----------|
|         1 |         2 |
#+TBLFM: @2='(org-table-get-remote-range @<$0 (string ?@ ?1 ?$ ?1))

#+TBLNAME: testname1
|    1 |

#+TBLNAME: testname2
|    2 |
```

Note the `(string ?@ ?1 ?$ ?1)`: this is necessary because before evaluating table formulae, all substitutions will be done first. If you use `"@1$1"` directly, it would have triggered the substitution mechanism and be substituted by the contents of the first cell in *this* table.

Answer (score 3):

There is some ugly hack for same effect without using `remote`:

1) it needs named variable for remote address

```
(setq eab/test-remote "@1$1")
```

2) it uses elisp expression (from org-table.el) instead `remote(tablename,@1$1)`

```
(defun eab/test-remote (x)
  `(car (read
     (org-table-make-reference
      (org-table-get-remote-range ,x eab/test-remote)
      't 't nil))))
```

3) worked example

```
| testname1 | testname2 |
|-----------+-----------|
|           |           |
#+TBLFM: @2='(eval (eab/test-remote @1))

#+TBLNAME: testname1
|    1 |

#+TBLNAME: testname2
|    2 |
```

4) result

```
| testname1 | testname2 |
|-----------+-----------|
|         1 |         2 |
```